# Change element id in real time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm making online shop. I have a button "Add product" with id #sendProduct. After click this button must change id to #deleteProduct. It changes id, but old handlers still being active after ID change. I mean when i click on button again, it reacts like id wasn't changed. 
Look at my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sendProduct').on('click', function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
        var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
        $.ajax({
            url: '/cart/add-to-cart',
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(id),
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (id) {
                $('#sendProduct').text('Delete from cart');
                $('#sendProduct').attr('data-id', id);
                $('#sendProduct').attr('id', 'deleteProduct');
                console.log($('#deleteProduct').attr('id'));
            }
        });
    });
    
    $('#deleteProduct').on('click', function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
        var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
        $.ajax({
            url: '/cart/delete-product',
            method: 'GET',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(id),
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (id) {
                $('#deleteButton').text('Add product');
                $('#deleteButton').attr('data-id', id);
                $('#deleteButton').attr('id', 'sendProduct');
            }
        })

    })
});
```

Comment: Changing a node's ID doesn't remove its existing handlers. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Skimming your code, I think a better solution would just be to have two buttons, only one of which is visible at a time. Just toggle their visibility when one is clicked.

Comment: Alternatively he can create a new event handler on the success promise if needed.

Comment: @AndrewHill and presumably remove the old handler too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code based on the suggestion in my comment.

```js
$(function () {
  $('#send').click(function () {
    console.log('You clicked send.');
    $('#send, #delete').toggleClass('hidden');
  });
  $('#delete').click(function () {
    console.log('You clicked delete.');
    $('#send, #delete').toggleClass('hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="send">Send</button>
<button id="delete" class="hidden">Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy and safe way is to use two buttons next to each other. One Shown, the other hidden. They will appear as the same button to the user. You could use toggle() instead of hide() and show() but it hurts readability, and is harder to debug.

```
<p>
    <button id='button-one'>Submit</button>
    <button id='button-two' style='display: none;'>Submit</button>
</p>

<script>
  $('#button-one').click(function(){
     $('#button-one').hide();
     $('#button-two').show();
     // do important stuff
  });

   $('#button-two').click(function(){
     // do more important stuff and maybe toggle the visibility
     // of the buttons again
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's a good idea to change the id attribute of an element, after all it is supposed to be unique for each element.

Have you try adding a class name to the button after it is clicked and binding a event handler to that class respectively?
set your button id just to something like #yourButton and then try to use classes for sendProduct and deleteProduct.
like this:

```
//your button may have sendProduct class a default class
$('.sendProduct').on('click', function () {
    //yout code
    $.ajax({
        //your ajax settings
        success: function (id) {
            $('#yourButton').text('Delete from cart');
            $('#yourButton')
                .toggleClass('sendProduct') //remove this class
                .toggleClass('deleteProduct'); //add this class
        }
    });
});

$('.deleteProduct').on('click', function () {
    //your code
    $.ajax({
        //your ajax settings
        success: function (id) {
            $('#youtButton').text('Add product');
            $('#youtButton')
                .toggleClass('deleteProduct') //remove this class
                .toggleClass('sendProduct'); // add this class
        }
    })
})
```